# Train a NN with "NOT of class C" labels

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

I have samples which I only know that they are NOT of class C. I don't know the correct label but I know which labels are not. I have seen people recomend "soft labels" for this situation together with the standard negative log likelihood loss (NLL).

For instance, I know that this sample is NOT of class 3, hence my label could be something like: [0.5, 0.5, 0]. That is, it could be either class 1 (prob 0.5) or class 2 (prob 0.5).

But that's not what I really wanted, right?

If the network outputs something like [1, 0, 0], that's 100% correct as far as I can tell. But the "soft label"/NLL will penalize such an answer.

What I really want is a loss that is 0 (zero) when class 3 is 0 (in the network output).

Meaning:

```
loss([0.3, 0.7, 0]) == 0
loss([1, 0, 0]) == 0
loss([0, 1, 0]) == 0
loss([0, 0, 1]) == some large value
```

If I negate the negative log-likehood loss (therefore have the positive log-likehood loss) with a label of [0, 0, 1], I kinda have what I want but will end up pushing the loss to -Inf, instead of zero.

So, I wonder if there's a loss that can do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

> If the network outputs something like [1, 0, 0], that's 100% correct as far as I can tell

Without labels there is no way to verify that's correct. You can do a binary classification tho, [1, 0] for A or B and [0, 1] for C, or go back and label the examples yourself if you are sure of the results.